# Animating Transitions between ViewBuilder Switch Cases

Tags: swiftui, enums, navigation, transition, viewbuilder

I have the following code

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content
        }
}

@ViewBuilder private var content: some View {
        switch someEnum {
        case .case1:
            view1()
        case .case2:
            view2()
        case .case3:
            view3()
        case .case4:
            view4()
        }
}
```

What's the best way to add transitions when the enum is changed so the switch between two views seems seamless similar to navigation links? Right now the view on top abruptly pops into the next view. I am looking to replicate a similar transition to that of a navigation link, where one view slides into the other on change.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can add a transition modifier to each view like the following.

```
view1()

   .transition(.scale(scale: 0.1, anchor: .bottom))

...

view2()

   .transition(.scale(scale: 0.1, anchor: .bottom))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I actually tried this before but it didn't end up changing anything. Any other ideas

Comment: try adding  .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: someEnum) on the NavigationView {}

Comment: Just tried this and had no luck. Thanks for the suggestion again. I tried putting the animation both on the content and navigationView and both had no luck in triggering the animation.